# Modify User Agent String on Redirect

Tags: javascript, user-agent

I am attempting to change the User-Agent string on a redirect.  So, if users hit this page, they are redirected to a different page using a defined user agent string.

So, this is the JavaScript I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (navigator.__defineGetter__) {
        navigator.__defineGetter__("userAgent", function () { 
            return 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 5_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/9B206';
        });
    } 
    else if (Object.defineProperty) { 
        Object.defineProperty(navigator, "userAgent", { 
            get: function () { 
                return 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 5_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/9B206';;
            }
        })
    }

    document.location = "http://www.whatsmyuseragent.com";
</script>
```

However, if you dump this into an empty HTML page and run it, you can see on the What's My User Agent website that the User-Agent string is NOT modified.  Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this, because it is "xss vulnerability". You javascript code invokes from up to down. First, navigator is updated, then page is redirected. When browser will start load "http://www.whatsmyuseragent.com" page, your changes'd cleared.

Comment: I understand the statement that Javascript is invoked from top to bottom for a given script chunk.  What I don't understand is your statement that the changes are cleared.  Is there a standard process by which any header changes are cleared before the redirect in order to prevent an XSS vulnerability?

Answer (score 0):

You can change ur user agent and sent get ajax request to "http://www.whatsmyuseragent.com" for trick this service.

e.g. [here in vanila js](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader()-method)
or

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function(request) {
    request.setRequestHeader("User-Agent","InsertUserAgentStringHere");
  }
});
```

But when you change your location, your user-agent would be as a default for browser.